# Chrome on mobile devices doesn't render <select> correctly

Tags: html, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have a VERY basic test page that on all but on the Chrome browser on mobile phones renders correctly. It is just a `<select>` list with a few `<option>`. I have added the "size=#" field, so on all other browsers, including Chrome on the desktop, that causes it to no longer be a pulldown selection box, but instead show all the items in the list so you can select them directly. Anyone know how to get Chrome on mobile devices to work the same?

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <select name="words" id="words" size=6 style="color:black; width:120px; height:200px;">
  <option value="abcde">abcde</option>
  <option value="abcfg">abcfg</option>
  <option value="abcxy">abcxy</option>
 </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it renders on most browsers:
[This is it on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRDFy.jpg)

Here is how it renders on Chrome on mobile: [This is on Chrome on Mobiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTfuI.jpg)

Comment: `</body>` should be `<body>`, which is probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: (Also fix the body tag, as mentioned by Obsidian Age)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    select {
        width: 150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed the <body> typo, that didn't fix it. And, unfortunately the style statement had no effect. Looks like you think the width is the cause of the browser ignoring the size= parameter so I just hard coded the width in the select definition, and while the box got wider, it still didn't show the "options" like it does on most other browsers.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is also broken with the way Chrome is rendering this, and maybe a clue as to what is going on, wthout the "size=#" parameter, the "pull down" shows the first option by default. With the size=# parameter, it is blank. You can barely see the little pull down handle on the far right to know it is trying to show a pull down.

Comment: Well, I was going to report this as a bug with Chromium,  but someone has already beaten me to it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1291865&q=html%20component%3ABlink%3EForms%3ESelect&can=2